# How personalize display format in TcxDateEdit

Tags: delphi, devexpress

The below code, set the format of the componente TcxDateEdit

```
  // In uses add cxFormats
  ShortDateFormat:='dd/mm/yyyy';
  DateSeparator  :='/';
  LongTimeFormat :='HH:MM';
  TimeSeparator  :=':';
  cxFormatController.UseDelphiDateTimeFormats := True;
  cxFormatController.GetFormats;
  cxFormatController.NotifyListeners;
```

But the format displayed and use is diferente.

[Issue, format diferent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nFjF.jpg)

> ¿How set to show the same format in that caption too?

[Ver pregunta en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/72548/30893)

Answer (score 0):

I use the same code and it work. That are global var, are you sure they are not overwritten?
Try to put that code in OnShow event

Comment: I try the code in a new project, and I put the code in OnShow event of my form, the behavior is the same. :/

Comment: I have devexpress version 6.59 and delphi 2017, and with that it works

Comment: I have delphi 2010 and devexpress 2.4 :/

Answer (score 0):

I Think that you must use SmartTextToDateFunc defined in DevExpress, 
see on
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2564